# FullSimplify does not work well

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

It is obvious that the answer to

```
FullSimplify[ - Log[-I x] + Log[ I x ] , Assumptions -> { x ∈ Reals, x != 0 } ]
```

is

```
 I π Sign[x]
```

whereas Mathematica gives back the same expression as the input..

How does one make it give the obvious answer?

Comment: But PowerExpand type of additional qualifications do not help if I want to eg. simplify Floor[ (π - 2 Arg[wm] - 2 Arg[x])/(4 π) ]  which has the obvious answer   -(1- UnitStep[x] UnitStep[wm])  when both x and wm are real and non-zero.

Answer (score 5):

You can include [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) in the list of [`TransformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions), and adjust the [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction) so that the intermediate forms produced by [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) are not discarded as being too complex:

```
FullSimplify[
    -Log[-I x] + Log[I x],
    Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals && x != 0,
    TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> True]&},
    ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#]+10 Count[#, _Log, Infinity]&)
] //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  -i \pi  & x<0 \\
>  i \pi  & \operatorname{True}
> \end{cases}$

Note the inclusion of the options `Assumptions->True` in the [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) call. With the default, [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) can produce incorrect results, while adding any option  (except [`Automatic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Automatic)) to [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) means the output will be correct. Also, I include the [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) wrapper so that the output is a reasonable facsimile of what you would see in Mathematica.

Answer (score 4):

With Carl Woll's insight that `Assumptions->True` needs to be used with `PowerExpand` in this case,

```
Assuming[{x ∈ Reals, x != 0}, -Log[-I x] + Log[I x] // 
 PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> True] & // Simplify]
```

[image]

Comment: This is somewhat less intimidating and I shall use this. Thanks to all who answered. However, I am disappointed that FullSimplify does not do what its name claims to do without further prodding and prompting...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with rules:

```
-Log[Conjugate[I a]]+Log[I a] //. {Log[Conjugate[I a]] -> Log[I a] - 2 I Arg[I a], Arg[I a] -> \[Pi]Sign[a]/2}

(*I \[Pi]Sign[a]*)
```

Comment: Sir, the import of the question is: I don't want to simplify expressions using my knowledge of mathematics, rather I want Mathematica to tell me the simplest version of the right answer without me having to supply predigested versions of the problem which is what your attempt at a solution is...

Comment: OK, let us try with this (the assumptions are basically the same, and follows Carl Woll & Bob Hanlon answers): `Assuming[Arg[z] == Sign[Im[z]], -Log[Conjugate[z]] + Log[z] // PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> True] & // FullSimplify]  (* 2 I Sign[Im[z]] *)`